# How to gengerate string from specific Array of Object in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I want to generate this string from Array of Object.

**String:**

```
"{{ ""t"": 3, ""s"":910},{ ""t"": 6, ""s"":4030},{ ""t"": 10, ""s"":2300}}"
```

**Array of Object**

```
0: {t: 3,s: 910}
1: {t: 6,s: 4030}
2: {t: 10,s: 2300}
```

Can anyone guide me how to do it.

Comment: the included string is not valid to be parsed. Can you make it valid or is it important to parse this kind of string?

Comment: it need to be like this only

Comment: 1. A valid JSON array should be wrapped with square bracket `[]`. 2. The string is not valid as the quotes for `t` is not escaped correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following code.

```
const arr = [
  { t: 3, s: 910 },
  { t: 6, s: 4030 },
  { t: 10, s: 2300 },
];

const result = arr.map(obj => {
  return Object.entries(obj).map(([key, value]) => `""${key}"": ${value}`).join(', ');
}).map(str => `{ ${str} }`).join(', ');

const finalResult = `"{{ ${result} }}"`;

console.log(finalResult);
```

log: "{{ { ""t"": 3, ""s"": 910 }, { ""t"": 6, ""s"": 4030 }, { ""t"": 10, ""s"": 2300 } }}"

Comment: hey your code works well but there is one extra curly brackets at the end and start of string I just updated finalResult Variable like this : const finalResult = `"{${result}}"`; Thanks brother.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using JSON.stringfy() function.
Here is code.

```
const arr = [
  { t: 3, s: 910 },
  { t: 6, s: 4030 },
  { t: 10, s: 2300 },
];
const formattedString =
  '{' + arr.map((item) => JSON.stringify(item)).join(', ') + '}';
console.log(formattedString);
```

Hope this is helpful.

Comment: hey double equates are important for me. Your code partially solved my problem. it resulted in this: {{"t":3,"s":910}, {"t":6,"s":4030}, {"t":10,"s":2300}}

Comment: yourStr = yourStr.replaceAll('"', '""')

Answer (score 0):

```
const arr = [
  { t: 3, s: 910 },
  { t: 6, s: 4030 },
  { t: 10, s: 2300 },
];
console.log((JSON.stringify(arr).replace('[','{').replace(/]$/,"}")).replaceAll('"', '""'));
```

Comment: Hey it seems your solution is better but it requires changes in "tsconfig.json" of which I am not allowed. Change is to Add "ES2021.String" to lib inside compilerOptions.